# Migrate down with only one migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, migration

In order to test a new Rails plugin that I wrote, I'd like to check if the migration of that plugin works correctly. So I created a new test app, added the plugin, generated the migration and migrated up (which works fine). I now would also like to check the down migration. But `rake db:migrate:down` wants a version number. What should I provide? It is the only migration and VERSION=0 doesn't work.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

See the [Official Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#rolling-back)

```
rake db:rollback
rake db:rollback STEP=3
rake db:migrate:down

# rollback-then-migrate-forward combo
rake db:migrate:redo
rake db:migrate:redo STEP=3
```

Comment: Thanks ... rollback works. But your second suggestion doesn't. STEP seems not to be valid for migrate:down.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. As you noted, and as described in the official guides that I linked to, `STEP` is respected by the `db:rollback` task but not the `db:migrate:down` task. I have corrected my answer.